# Rails - multiple forms unintentionally using the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, form-for

I've got a page showing details for every @user. Each user has an enrolment, which can has a comment. When I e.g. do this:

```
<% @user.each do |u| %>
  <% the_enrolment = Enrolment.where(user_id: u).first %>
<% end %>
```

Then in every iteration the enrolment is a different enrolment, as the user changes in every iteration. So far, so simple.

But when I pass this enrolment variable (while looping through) to a partial which contains a form, like this:

```
<%= render 'the_partial', enrolment: the_enrolment %>
```

With this form (in the partial view):

```
<%= form_for enrolment, :url => the_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment %>
<%= f.submit "Save" %>
```

Then, in the finally rendered page, every form uses the same enrolment. (They all have the same id and every text_are is pre filled with the content of **one** of them. What am I doing wrong here?

The complete iteration looks like this:

```
@user.each do |u|
  the_enrolment = Enrolment.where(user_id: u).first
  <%= the_enrolment %> # correct id
  <%= render 'the_partial', enrolment: the_enrolment %>
end
```

Thank you very much!

**Update**

Here is an update with the newest informations. The problem seems to be that the form is placed inside a twitter bootstrap modal. Here is the whole `partial`:

```
<%= enrolment.id %> # here it's the correct id
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Admin Comment</h3>
  </div>

  <%= form_for enrolment, :url => the_path, remote: true do |f| %>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          <%= "enrolment in modal: #{enrolment.id}" %> # at this place the id is ALWAYS the id of the very first enrolment
          <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
          <%= f.text_area :comment_admin %>

          <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success", id: "admin-comment-submit-button" %>
        </p>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If I delete everything on this page concerning the modal, the form works.

Comment: Are you sure you have the render within the loop? it sounds like you're experiencing what would happen if it were after.  `<% @user.each do |u| %><%= render 'the_partial', enrolment: Enrolment.where(user_id: u).first %><% end %>`

Comment: Yes I'm absolutely sure. If I output the enrolment id right above the partial rendering, the enrolment id is a different every time. But if I render that same enrolment id in the first line of the partial, it stays the same. Weird right? I've just checked, the id inside the partial is always the id of the very first enrolment.

Comment: how come your loop and assignment lines aren't in `<% %>` tags

Comment: Ummmm...  Are you using ActiveRecord relations?  For example, does your Enrollment model (which you have spelled Enrolment) have as "belongs_to :user" in it and your User model has a "has_one :enrollment"?  Putting your partial aside that will dramatically simplify what you are doing in your logic because you can then simply do Enrollment.all.each {|e| e.user.comment}

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I just noticed, the enrolment variable changes inside the partial too, it's just the form_for's only using only the first enrolment being passed. Yeah that's right with the <% %>, it was just a draft I made for the question.

Comment: Yes, the user and enrollment models have got relations. Enrollment `belongs_to :user` and user `has_many :enrollments'. Unfortunately this is just a small part of the whole iteration so I can't reduce it like that.

Comment: in that case you can just do `u.enrollment` but i don't think that these changes will solve your issue, still looking into it

Comment: I've moved the form out of the partial, everything works now. What am I missing here?

Comment: try using `locals: { :enrollment => u.enrollment }` within the render call.  What version of rails are you using? Also maybe you `expose` or `let` an enrollment variable in your controller that conflicts and maybe that messes with it?

Comment: I'm using Rails v3.2.13. No there is no other variable conflicting with the name. I've changed it to `locals:` but that didn't help. Could this be some kind of locals bug? ...But I can impossible be the first one having this problem then.

Comment: I've got an suspicion, does it make a difference to the form_for if it is placed inside a hidden bootstrap modal the time it's getting rendered? Ok I thinks thats the problem... I'm sorry for skipping this detail, I would never have thought that this would make a difference.

Comment: it shouldn't, because even if it's hidden, it's just html on the page

Comment: Ok thats weird, because if I delete the surrounding div, it works perfectly. It's this bootstrap modal, maybe there is something special about it? http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals